# Nginx 403 Forbidden for files simply for being inside of the home folder

Tags: nginx, fedora

I installed standard Nginx on Fedora 29 using standard dnf.

I changed user to "root" at the top of nginx.conf. I also tried with user set to "username" at the top of nginx.conf. I also tried this while leaving user at the default "nginx".

Inside of the server block:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html (THIS WORKS!)
root /home/username/path/to/destination (403 FORBIDDEN)
```

I have copied index.html into every folder location between the place that works and the destination that is forbidden, like so:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html (THIS WORKS!)
/usr/share/nginx/index.html (THIS WORKS!)
/usr/share/index.html (THIS WORKS!)
/usr/index.html (THIS WORKS!)
/index.html (THIS WORKS!)
/home/index.html (403 FORBIDDEN)
/home/username/index.html (403 FORBIDDEN)
/home/username/path/index.html (403 FORBIDDEN)
/home/username/path/to/index.html (403 FORBIDDEN)
/home/username/path/to/destination/index.html (403 FORBIDDEN)
```

I progressively changed the nginx.conf server block root line to each of the above folders and I restart nginx each time:

```
root    /usr/share/nginx/html;              (THIS WORKS!)
root    /usr/share/nginx;                   (THIS WORKS!)
root    /usr/share;                         (THIS WORKS!)
root    /usr;                               (THIS WORKS!)
root    /;                                  (THIS WORKS!)
root    /home;                              (403 FORBIDDEN)
root    /home/username;                     (403 FORBIDDEN)
root    /home/username/path;                (403 FORBIDDEN)
root    /home/username/path/to;             (403 FORBIDDEN)
root    /home/username/path/to/destination; (403 FORBIDDEN)
```

Each time:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Here are the permissions on each of these folders:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root /usr/share/nginx/html
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root root /usr/share/nginx
drwxr-xr-x.  279 root root /usr/share
drwxr-xr-x.  12 root root /usr
dr-xr-xr-x.  19 root  root /
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root  root /home
drwxr-xr-x. 26 username username /home/username
drwxrwxrwx. 15 username username /home/username/path
drwxr-xr-x.  4 username username /home/username/path/to
drwxr-xr-x.  6 username username /home/username/path/to/destination
```

Here are the permissions on the index.html file that was copied to all of the above folders:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3700 Nov 20 12:32 index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

apply access context security for read and write http services in directory.

in readhat, fedora and centos default selinux is enforsed.

```
chown nginx:nginx -R "dir_name"
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "dir_name"
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "dir_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you shouldn't have changed user in nginx.conf. The most common recommendation is to keep default user **www-data**.

It's better add your *username* to www-data group or something like that.
Try to search in this direction, maybe this link  will help you: https://askubuntu.com/a/9411